# IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException when no entity is found. First returned when multiple are found

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to find the reason for one strange behavior. Lets say I have Spring data repository which contains a few methods. One of them has a signature like this:

```
public Entity findByEntityKeyAndValidToDateAfterAndCorrectionDateAfter(BigInteger entityKey, Timestamp validToDate, Timestamp correctionDate);
```

I receive an issue with stacktrace with the following error:

> org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException

I decided to add two records which have to be returned when I execute this query. 
After calling this method instead of throwing the exception the query returns only one of the results. This was strange to my that is why I copy the query from the log and execute it on my SQL developer with the same parameters. The query return both results. I try to change the method signature to return list of entities:

```
public List<Entity> findByEntityKeyAndValidToDateAfterAndCorrectionDateAfter(BigInteger entityKey, Timestamp validToDate, Timestamp correctionDate);
```

In this case, the query returns two results.

Any idea why this may happen? And why this query does not throw this exception?

Spring data version is 1.10.1.RELEASE

Comment: What kind of repository are you using? Is it a CRUD repository?

Comment: No, it is Repository.

Comment: can you please post the full stack trace of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

When using a find method returning a singular type, the following semantics should apply:

0 elements found => return `null` or `Optional.empty` if applicable.

1 element found => return that element.

more than 1 element found => exception should be thrown.

Since this is not what you seem to see please upgrade to at least the current minor version (1.10.11), but preferably to the current GA release(1.11.7). If the problem still persists please create an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA/?selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.jira-projects-plugin:summary-panel